# Multiple file upload is not working using jQuery and Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, php-5.6

I want to do multiple file upload. I tried lot but I'm not able to get the solution. Whenever I am uploading multiple images, it is taking only first image value.

```
formData.append('file[]', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

I am trying like this I am getting single image

```
formData.append('file[]', $('input[type=file]')[1].files[1]);
```

I am trying like this I am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

```js
$("#basicFormBtn").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var formData = new FormData($('#basicForm')[0]);
    formData.append('file[]', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url :"test_session.php",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(exception){
            alert('Exeption:'+exception);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Basic Form</h2>
        <form id="basicForm">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 form-group">
                    <label for="name">User Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="Enter userName" name="userName" required="">
                </div>
            </div>
  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5 form-group">
                    <label for="album">Album:</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" required="" multiple> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="basicFormBtn">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting output like this (in `test_session.php`) with `print_r($_FILES)`;

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1.png
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/png
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp5.6\tmp\phpC3C0.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 166275
                )

        )

     )
```

Comment: You need to append each image with a loop function, like `for` or `for each`

Comment: You don't need to append anything if it is already in the form and all the files are already in the form object. Get rid of the files append

Answer (score 2):

**Try this you will get all uploaded files.**

Your old code

```
<input type="file" name="file" required="" multiple>
```

Change with this

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" required="" multiple>
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you not set array value to your append file input. try this :

```
var i=0;//set default array value
$("#basicFormBtn").click(function(e){
i++;//set next array value
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData();
var formData = new FormData($('#basicForm')[0]);
formData.append('file['+i+']', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);//push next array value
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url :"test_session.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(exception){
        alert('Exeption:'+exception);
    }
});
```

});